# flutter myFriendlyChat crashes after firebase google signIn integration

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I am trying the codelabs firebase integration tutorial.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/

I did all the steps <= step 6 configuring firebase and local app, but after running the app it crashes. Console leaves no error, this is console log:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/564bd94e1e0f90548f3d7a9882699874

I configured the app only for iOS, not for android and I am running the app in iOS Simulator. Maybe it makes the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Xcode>Runner>info.plist>Right click>open as Source> and then check whether you have this:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <!-- TODO Replace this value: -->
            <!-- Copied from GoogleServices-Info.plist key REVERSED_CLIENT_ID -->
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.861823949799-vc35cprkp249096uujjn0vvnmcvjppkn</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

and if you have Facebook login as well, then it should look like this:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>google</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.995426033439-887653460s954g71jfbf2t9730tl0jmi</string>
            <string></string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>facebook</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb25634XXXXXXXXXX</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, I missed one step for iOS.

Configure Google Sign-In on iOS at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#5

After adding CFBundleURLTypes to Info.plist (not GoogleService-Info.plist), my app started working with Google Sign In.

I hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason this step is missing in the code lab. You have to copy a section from GoogleService-Info.plist to Info.plist. See https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in